# Get query params in NextJS without a componet

Tags: next.js, query-string

I have my Nextjs app running with redux-saga, I have a saga where I import the Api base URL from a config file, like this:

`import { PROMOTION_SERVICE_BASE_URL } from '../../config/api';`

This config file is `api.ts`, inside this file I am trying to get the query params to override the current one if I put something like this in the URL:

`?service_base_override=http://localhost:4000/test`.

How can I get this query param inside this `ts` file?

Comment: Won't this file be used in your components? Could you not pass the query param to the function that needs it from the component? It's not entirely clear how you're trying to use the query param, could you add the logic where you want to use it?

Comment: I am importing this file in a saga file.